# Creation of ECDSA private key given curve and private exponent?

Tags: c++, private-key, crypto++, ecdsa, signer

I am new to cryptopp and have been struggling for a while with the creation of  private keys for ECDSA signing.

I have a hex encoded private exponent `E4A6CFB431471CFCAE491FD566D19C87082CF9FA7722D7FA24B2B3F5669DBEFB`. This is stored as a string.

I want to use this to sign a text block using ECDSA.  My code looks a bit like this

```
string Sig::genSignature(const string& privKeyIn, const string& messageIn)
{
   AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
   ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
   privateKey.AccessGroupParameters().Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1());
   privateKey.Load(StringSource(privKeyIn, true, NULL).Ref());
   ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);

   // Determine maximum size, allocate a string with that size
   size_t siglen = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
   string signature(siglen, 0x00);

   // Sign, and trim signature to actual size
   siglen = signer.SignMessage(prng, (const byte *) messageIn.data(), (size_t) messageIn.length(),       (byte*)signature.data());
   signature.resize(siglen);
   cout << signature.data() << endl;
   return signature;
}
```

This code generates the following error in Visual studio on the when I try to do privateKey.load(...)

```
First-chance exception at 0x7693C42D in DLLTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr at memory location 0x0033EEA8.
Unhandled exception at 0x7693C42D in DLLTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr at memory location 0x0033EEA8.
```

I am guessing I am doing something a bit stupid... any help would be great???

PS I had a similar issue using ECDH for GMAC generation but got round this by saving the key as a SECByteBlock but this 'trick' doesnt seem to work in this case.

Comment: *"I had a similar issue using ECDH for GMAC generation..."* - Its not clear to me where the intersection between ECDH and GMAC lies. You might want to ask for a code review on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ECDH is used when creating a shared secret that is then used to create the AES key I use for the GMAC gen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DLLTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CryptoPP::BERDecodeErr ...

You have a private exponent, and *not* a private key. So you should *not* call `Load` on it. That's causing the Crypto++ `BERDecodeErr` exception.

The answer is detailed on the [ECDSA wiki page](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ecdsa#Private_Key_2), but its not readily apparent. You need to perform the following to initialize the `privateKey` given the curve and exponent::

```
string exp = "E4A6CFB431471CFCAE491FD566D19C87082CF9FA7722D7FA24B2B3F5669DBEFB";
exp.insert(0, "0x");

Integer x(exp.c_str());
privateKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), x);
```

Prepending the `"0x"` ensures the `Integer` class will parse the ASCII string correctly. You can also append a `"h"` character to the string. You can see the parsing code for `Integer` class at [Integer.cpp](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/integer_8cpp_source.html) around line 2960 in the `StringToInteger` function.

---

Here's another way to do the same thing:

```
string exp = "E4A6CFB431471CFCAE491FD566D19C87082CF9FA7722D7FA24B2B3F5669DBEFB";

HexDecoder decoder;
decoder.Put((byte*)exp.data(), exp.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

Integer x;
x.Decode(decoder, decoder.MaxRetrievable());

privateKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), x);
```

The [`HexDecoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hexdecoder) will perform the ASCII to binary conversion for you. The buffer held by the `HexDecoder` will then be consumed by the `Integer` using its [`Decode (BufferedTransformation &bt, size_t inputLen, Signedness=UNSIGNED)`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html) method.

---

And here is another way using [`HexDecoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Hexdecoder) (Crypto++ is as bad as scripting languages at times :)...

```
string exp = "E4A6CFB431471CFCAE491FD566D19C87082CF9FA7722D7FA24B2B3F5669DBEFB";
StringSource ss(exp, true /*punpAll*/, new HexDecoder);

Integer x;
x.Decode(ss, ss.MaxRetrievable());

privateKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), x);
```

---

After initializing the key, you should validate it:

```
bool result = privateKey.Validate( prng, 3 );
if( !result ) { /* Handle error */ }
```

---

This will output binary data:

```
cout << signature.data() << endl;
```

If you want something printable/readable, run it though a Crypto++ [HexEncoder](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder).

Comment: thanks for the answer!! this has worked a treat.. I will post my final code for others.. I was wonderign if you could help with a similar question relating to public keys? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315687/cryptopp-creation-of-ecdsa-publickey-given-curve-and-key-as-hex-string

Comment: @jww , if it had been the private key string instead of private key exponent string,  then how to generate private key ?I have posted my question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860777/use-already-generated-public-key-in-ecies-using-cryptopp .Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

for others looking for this later

```
string genSignature(const string& privKeyIn, const string& messageIn)
{
    CryptoPP::Integer secretNumber(genSecretNumber(privKeyIn, messageIn));
    AutoSeededRandomPool secretNumberGenerator;

    if (encryptBase::debug)
    {
        cout << "secret number: " << secretNumber << endl;
    }

    SecByteBlock message(convertHexStrToSecByteBlock(messageIn));
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
    string exp(privKeyIn);
    exp.insert(0, "0x");
    Integer x(exp.c_str());
    privateKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), x);
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    if (!privateKey.Validate(prng, 3))
    {
        cout << "unable to verify key" << endl;
        return "failed to verify key";
    }

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);
    size_t siglen = signer.MaxSignatureLength();
    string signature(siglen, 0x00);
    siglen = signer.SignMessage(secretNumberGenerator, message.BytePtr(), message.size(),     (byte*)signature.data());
    signature.resize(siglen);

    string encoded;
    HexEncoder encoder;
    encoder.Put((byte *) signature.data(), signature.size());
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    word64 size = encoder.MaxRetrievable();
    if (size)
    {
        encoded.resize(size);
        encoder.Get((byte*)encoded.data(), encoded.size());
    }

    return encoded;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `secretNumberGenerator` since you have the `prng`. You can use `HexEncoder encoder(new StringSink(encoded))` and remove the code to retrieve the hex encoded value. The `HexEncoder` will put the result in the string due to the attached `StringSink`. You will still need to call `encoder.MessageEnd()`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.. I will update the code shortly. the code above isnt the final version as in the 'real' application the secret number is no random.  It uses a custom class to return a precalculated value.