# Creation of ECDSA public key given curve and public point?

Tags: c++, hex, crypto++, ecdsa

I am struggling with the creation of a ECDSA public key from a string representation of a public key i.e

```
string     devicePublicKey("86FB5EB3CA0507226BE7197058B9EC041D3A3758D9D9C91902ACA3391F4E58AEF13AFF63CC4EF68942B9B94904DC1B890EDBEABD16B992110624968E894E560E");
```

previously I found that I had to prefix this key with '04' so not sure if this is require this time?

I am trying to generate it to use in verifying a signature

```
string ecs04b2ExpSignature("0199E984CEC75DDCA7F1DDF6E53E2E67352A2BE38A4B66F8ED596606FAB983FF300CAA76DE88CED9D563A5C03E8F3A7C000780F3F2061C611E9AA0B18B460D77");
```

where the data to be signed is

```
string      ecs04b2SigningData("020000000000000001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE123456789ABCDEF000B3DA2000000100000300000003030003000300");
```

My rough code for now looks like this

```
SecByteBlock message(convertHexStrToSecByteBlock(messageIn));
SecByteBlock signature(convertHexStrToSecByteBlock(signatureIn));

ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
string inPublicKey("04");
inPublicKey.append(pubKeyIn);
SecByteBlock pubKey = encryptBase::convertHexStrToSecByteBlock(inPublicKey);



ECP::Point p;
publicKey.AccessGroupParameters().Initialize(CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1());
publicKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().DecodePoint(p, pubKey, publicKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().EncodedPointSize(true));
publicKey.SetPublicElement(p);

//ByteQueue qt;
//qt.Put((byte*)exp.c_str(),(size_t)exp.size());
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
bool result = publicKey.Validate(prng, 3);
if (result) 
{  
    // Load public key (in ByteQueue, X509 format)
    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);

    bool result = verifier.VerifyMessage(message.data(), messageIn.size(), signature.data(), signature.size());
    if (result)
        cout << "Verified signature on message" << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Failed to verify signature on message" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Failed to validate key" << endl;
}
```

this is chopped together so wont build. Any help would be great

PS I asked a similar question relating to private keys here [Creation of ECDSA private key given curve and private exponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232053/creation-of-ecdsa-private-key-given-curve-and-private-exponent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is detailed on the [ECDSA wiki page](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ecdsa#Public_Key_2), but its not readily apparent. You need to perform the following to initialize the `publicKey` given the curve and public point:

```
string pt = "2DB45A3F21889438B42C8F464C75292BACF5FDDB5DA0B492501B299CBFE92D8F"
            "DB90FC8FF4026129838B1BCAD1402CAE47FE7D8084E409A41AFCE16D63579C5F";

HexDecoder decoder;
decoder.Put((byte*)pt.data(), pt.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

ECP::Point q;
size_t len = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
// len should be GetField().MaxElementByteLength()

q.identity = false;
q.x.Decode(decoder, len/2);
q.y.Decode(decoder, len/2);

ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
publicKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), q);

bool result = publicKey.Validate( prng, 3 );
if( result )
{
    cout << "Validated public key" << endl;
}
else
{
    cerr << "Failed to validate public key" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

const ECP::Point& qq = publicKey.GetPublicElement();
cout << "Q.x: " << std::hex << qq.x << endl;
cout << "Q.y: " << std::hex << qq.y << endl;
```

The program above produces the following results.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Validated public key
Q.x: 2db45a3f21889438b42c8f464c75292bacf5fddb5da0b492501b299cbfe92d8fh
Q.y: db90fc8ff4026129838b1bcad1402cae47fe7d8084e409a41afce16d63579c5fh
```

---

You can't use `GetField().MaxElementByteLength()` because the only thing available are the `x` and `y` coordinates. Things like field size won't be available until you initialize the underlying [`DL_GroupParameters_EC< EC >`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_d_l___group_parameters___e_c.html) in the public key.

As an example, the following causes a segmentation fault:

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
unsigned int u = publicKey.GetGroupParameters().GetCurve().GetField().MaxElementByteLength();
cout << "Field element length: " << u << endl;
```

---

You can tamper with the public key to ensure a validation failure with:

```
q.y.Decode(decoder, len/2);
q.y++;
```

Comment: this works perfectly! thank you so much for all your help.  I struggle a litle with the cryptoPP wiki as there seems to be some dublication of content.  I was using http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm Please note I have updated the public key in the example above (my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to your second question on how to use `VerifyMessage`:

```
...
publicKey.Initialize(ASN1::secp256r1(), q);

string msg = "020000000000000001FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE123456789ABCDEF000B3DA2000000100000300000003030003000300";
string sig = "0199E984CEC75DDCA7F1DDF6E53E2E67352A2BE38A4B66F8ED596606FAB983FF300CAA76DE88CED9D563A5C03E8F3A7C000780F3F2061C611E9AA0B18B460D77";

string mm, ss;

decoder.Detach(new StringSink(mm));
decoder.Put((byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

decoder.Detach(new StringSink(ss));
decoder.Put((byte*)sig.data(), sig.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);
result = verifier.VerifyMessage((byte*)mm.data(), mm.size(), (byte*)ss.data(), ss.size());

if( result )
{
    cout << "Verified message" << endl;
}
else
{ 
    cerr << "Failed to verify message" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Calling `Detach` on the `HexDecoder` deletes the current filter, and replaces it with the new filter. In the code above, its the `StringSink`. You have to do it to ensure memory is not leaked.

Your message does not verify under the public key:

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
Validated public key
Failed to verify message
```

You can also try to verify the ASCII message rather than the binary message, but it fails to verify too:

```
decoder.Attach(new StringSink(mm));
decoder.Put((byte*)msg.data(), msg.size());
decoder.MessageEnd();

// Swap in the ASCII message for the binary message
mm = msg;
```

So someone gave you the wrong message, the wrong signature or the wrong public key (or some combination).

Comment: this worked perfectly.  I have updated the key in the example above and the message is verified ok.  Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Can I use this also to get the r and s values of an ECDSA signature? And if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but, did you manage to get r and s eventually?